# Timeout when polling for Unlocked Package Version Create report

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, bug, unlocked-package

I have an **Unlocked Package** with many dependencies. Its creating takes **more than 30 minutes**.

My Backend code is **polling every 5 seconds** using

```
sfdx force:package:version:create:report --json --packagecreaterequestid 08c...3AAK
```

and after a while it's failing with this error

> Timeout exceeded, while waiting for force:package:version:create:report response

**What am I doing wrong?**

1. Is the polling frequency too high?
2. What is a recommended frequency?
3. Are the limits I am running in documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the polling frequency too high?

Most likely, yes. I do remember having problems with being impatient before I discovered force:package:version:create --wait.

> What is a recommended frequency?

force:package:version:create --wait sleeps in 30 second intervals. I'd consider this a recommended strategy.

> Are the limits I am running in documented anywhere?

Not that I'm aware of, but generally polling every five seconds in Salesforce is not ideal.

Comment: We are trying to use wait but I will keep this open and wait for answers that explain what limits were run into AND why there is the need for a polling report command when there is a wait param.

Comment: The wait param other then I remember AND it is documented requires a numeric minute value.  If I put 60 there and package creation takes 2h it will not work. So I think polling is the better more scalable approach.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Maybe. I've always just set to 100, haven't had a problem yet, and that was with 10k+ elements in the package. Still, I think 30 seconds between checks is probably reasonable, since that's what the CLI does. Hopefully we'll get a response from Wade or someone today.